# AngularJS 2.0 TypeScript Intellij idea (or webstorm) - ES6 import syntax

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript1.5, typescript1.4

Trying to make these steps to make [AngularJS 2.0 sample](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) app running.

On that step, putting code in app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

Got latest 14.1.3 `IntelliJ IDE`.

But seems it does not understand `'import'` (highlighting complain)

**Q:** IS that because It does not support yet TypeScript 1.5? (it the IDE settings I can see embedded 1.4 version).
Could it be compiled with that IDE?

Answer (score 20):

it look like you didn't specify the compiler arguments to tell which module loader to use, also you want to make sure you are using the latest TypeScript Compiler, to this date the latest was 1.5.0 beta.

**First**

You can download the bin of the TypeScript compiler **tsc** and all other related files on their GitHub Repository:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/bin

or you can also install it as a Node.js Package:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

**Second**

You need to configure intelliJ properly by changing the Compiler version to **custom** and point to the location of the latest TypeScript bin folder

in IntelliJ press **Ctrl+Alt+S**, search for **TypeScript** and under **Languages & Frameworks** select TypeScript, make sure your IntelliJ is up to date though.

And to solve the problem you are asking here specify the following Command Line options:

```
--module "amd" --target "es5"
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Third**

It is worth mentioning that the TypeScript 1.5 compiler and Angular 2 are both in Beta so this answer could be irrelevant in the following weeks or month.

Enjoy!

Dany

Comment: On Windows, if you download typescript from NPM for example `https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript`.. You should point your compiler version to `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin` This is the default install location.

Comment: For me (MacOS X) Typescript Compiler location needed this location : `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib` Note it's `lib` and not `bin`. I installed with `npm install -g typescript` like indicated in this post. This link may be helpful https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/typescript.html

Comment: Ubuntu was also `/usr/local/lib/node_modules_typescript/lib/`. Wish I would have checked comments before spending 15 minutes googling for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need select javascript version in Preferences page.

Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript

on the right page. JavaScript language version dropdown menu.
on my idea it's has some item below.

JavaScript 1.5
ECMAScript 5.1
JavaScript 1.6
JavaScript 1.7
JavaScript 1.8
JavaScript 1.8.6
ECMAScript 6
...

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in IntelliJ where you can define a custom typescript version. Default is 1.4 but you can download 1.5 beta and assign that. The only problem with the sample I've seen is to activate 1.5 new argument to generate decorators metadata. IntelliJ always report that the TS process stopped.