# AngularJS 2.0 compile to ES6

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I can get the [AngularJS 2.0 5 Minute Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) working in my `IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4` following this Stackoverflow Answer regarding [AngularJS 2.0 TypeScript Intellij idea (or webstorm) - ES6 import syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30655907/463196).

However, this appears to be targeting compilation of `TypeScript` to `EcmaScript 5`.

I wanted to see if I could get `AngularJS 2.0 Typescript` to compile to `EcmaScript 6`.

**Issue 1:** When I change the `TypeScript` compiler to target `ES6` ...

[image: IntelliJ TypeScript compiler]

I start getting a `TypeScript` compiler error:

```
Error: TS1204: Cannot compile modules into 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', or 'umd' 
when targeting 'ES6' or higher.
```

I can get around it by removing the `--module "amd"` `TypeScript` compiler option.

This does beg the question: without specifying amd, what sort of module format is `ES6` using?

**Issue 2:**

After modifying the `TypeScript` compiler options so they appear as follows:

[image: IntelliJ TypeScript compiler]

I start getting errors regarding:

```
Error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'
```

[image: TypeScript Error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise']

Has anyone seen this before?  I suspect it has something to do with the `AngularJS 2.0 Quickstart` specifying ES-6 Promise and it being installed globally, but have not been able to figure out how to resolve it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: WTH would you want to compile to ES6?

Comment: @Bergi  No pragmatic reason ... I am trying to learn Angular 2.0, TypeScript, ES6.  In the process, I'm testing the boundaries and trying to make sure that I can compile to ES6 since it was documented as possible to do.

Comment: Somebody posted an issue [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/5015) about the problem. Also, es6 has its own module format see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303675/cannot-compile-external-modules-into-amd-or-commonjs-when-targeting-es6-or-highe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I've figured out the issues that was preventing me from compiling the `AngularJS 2.0` Quickstart into `EcmaScript 6` :

**Solution:**

1. As basarat mentioned, `ES6` does not support `amd`.  I did try specifying `--module="system"` compiler flag, but that did not work either, still got the error message

   Error: TS1204: Cannot compile modules into 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', or     'umd' when targeting 'ES6' or higher.

The fix for that is to ***NOT*** specify any sort of module.

My new `TypeScript` compiler options:

```
--experimentalDecorators --target "es6"
```

2. The command `tsd install angular2 es6-promise rx rx-lite` pulls down ES6 promise, as one would expect.  The problem is that `TypeScript 1.5.3` includes a `TypeScript Definition file` in the `bin` called `lib.es6.d.ts`.

This contains a definition of Promise, which conflicts with the one that was pulled down via the `tsd` command.

I removed the `es6-promise` directory from my Angular2 project `typings` folder (the one that was created by running `tsd`).

3. (this felt like a hack): I went into the `angular2.d.ts` file and removed the following line:

   `///reference path=<"../es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts"/>`

The reason I had to remove this is `AngularJS 2.0 TypeScript Type Definition` looks for ES6 Promise at a peer level.  Since the `TypeScript compiler` (at least the version I am using, `TypeScript 1.5.3` contains the ES6 Promise already) and they conflicted.

Answer (score 5):

> without specifying amd, what sort of module format is ES6 using?

With target es6 only `system` is supposed to be allowed. The fact that `amd` worked is actually a bug.

> Duplicate identifier 'Promise'

With target es6 `lib.d.ts` changes into `lib.es6.d.ts` ([this file](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4c7b214a69c97eb1746b94712ff9a4c2202e2dca/lib/lib.es6.d.ts)) which has an included definition for `Promise`.

Recommended fix:

- Compile with `--nolib` and include `lib.d.ts` [into your project](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4c7b214a69c97eb1746b94712ff9a4c2202e2dca/lib/lib.d.ts)

More about lib.d.ts http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

Answer (score 5):

Tutorial for Angular2 changed since answer by Philip, it no longer uses es6-promise but I still get this error when trying to transpile to es6.

The trick is to exclude the browser typings when using es6. You can do that adding `"typings/browser", "typings/browser.d.ts",` to the exclude option in tsconfig.js.

If you are transpiling to es6 use:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

If you are transpiling to es5 then use:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank You!
I sort of understand the excludes, but until I changed the module to system instead of commonjs (or replaced my entire tsconfig with this last es5 one) it wouldn't work.

It seems a lot of people will face this issue with old tutorials, thinking it's an old version of typescript issue...

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for a long time. I tried all information here with no luck. I was referencing typings in my boot file.

`/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />`

Where typings has the following structure

`typings
-- globals
---- es6-collections
---- es6-promise
---- node`

I had also removed the @type node module completely. Also trying various 'excludes' and 'types' in the tsconfig.json file. Without success.

After much messing around I found if I just included 'node' index.d.ts and not the other content from 'typings' it worked fine.

Hence

`/// <reference path="../../typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />`

in my Angular 2 boot file did it for me.